# RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs for WPF slider - "type or namespace could not be found"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, windows-8.1

I'm following [this example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/slider-control-in-wpf/) to create a simple slider whose value I can use in my Windows Store app.

However, when I get to creating Something_ValueChanged (as per the example) and try to add a RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs of type double as an argument to this method, I am getting the standard "The type or namespace name could not be found" error.

I've tried looking around at other examples like [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/slider) which seemed to suggest I was missing 'using' imports such as System.Windows and System.Windows.Controls. However, I am also getting that the latter is missing (type or namespace...)!

Here's the relevant sections of code I am using in my MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs:

xaml:

```
<Grid ...>
    <Grid ...>
        ...
        <Slider  Name="BinSize" Width="300" Height="20"
                     Background="Gray" Maximum="100" Minimum="0"
                     Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="50"
                     ValueChanged="BinSize_ValueChanged"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

cs:

```
private void BinSize_ValueChanged(object sender,
    RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    //nothing yet
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are coding for a windows 8 app the method signature/content should look something like this:

```
    private void BinSize_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string msg = String.Format("Current value: {0}", e.NewValue);
        this.textBlock1.Text = msg;
    }
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.slider.aspx) is the MSDN example toward the bottom of the page.

The tutorial you are following will for the most part work with a Windows 8 App but it is designed for a WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) application so it may vary slightly. Whenever you get errors I would google the name of the item you are using and find the windows 8 version.

I hope this helps. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out and add as the accepted answer once I get this to work!

Comment: Not a problem glad to help!